# How to prevent a button added by a userscript [GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey] from submitting a form

Tags: event-handling, dom-events, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

Let me start off by saying that the code in question is part of a `UserScript` and, as such, normal DOM rules and Javascript methods do not work.

Here is the situation:

I have written a UserScript that interacts with an online chat site. I have a number of `button` that are generated within the user script.  Some of these buttons are located inside of a form, while many of them are not.

Elements added through GreaseMonkey live in two worlds -- they live on the page DOM and they live in the slightly elevated world of UserScripts, which mean that these lines:

```
event.preventDefault = true;
event.stopPropagation = true;
```

prevent the rest of the `UserScript` actions from running, but it does not stop the button from causing a form submit.

As a work around, I am building `span` elements instead of a `button`.  This works, but it really breaks the visual layout of the chat room.

Does anyone know a way to prevent elements added by `UserScripts` to prevent `form` submissions?  Failing that, I'll dream that someone knows how to make a `span` look like a native `button`.

Edit: I have a solution which seems to be working -- but I haven't fully tested it under every UserScript environment:

```
  // Yes, yes, poorly named but it was a SPAN
  // userWindow is an alias for unsafeWindow.
  // (Used to run under a userScript environment for IE and I had to emulate a lot)
  var span = document.createElement("input");
  span.value = text;
  span.type = "button";
  span.className = "cpbutton";

  // Add it to the body just long enough to set up a page-level, DOM0 event handler
  var body = userWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tname = "IAmTheVeryModelOfAModernMajorGeneral";     
  span.id = tname;
  body.appendChild(span);
  userWindow.document.getElementById(tname).onclick = function() {return false;};
  body.removeChild(span);
  span.id = "";
```

Comment: `to prevent elements added by UserScripts to prevent form submissions`. does that mean you want to prevent or allow submiting the form?

Comment: I want to *prevent* the form submission.

Comment: @Brock -- Yes.. "TamperMonkey" -- Or more specially, TamperMonkey Beta.  Shhesh, My proofreading is usually better than this.  (I'm dyslexic.)

Comment: No problem, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: just to let you know, `unsafeWindow.document.getElementById(tname).onclick = function() {return false;};` prevented my form from submiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the W3C spec for `<button>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button).
By default, a `<button>` element acts as a submit button inside a form.  This means that `event.preventDefault()` (the correct usage, BTW), on the click handler, may not be enough to stop the form submit.

In that case you could intercept the form's submit event too **BUT**, the smart thing to do is to use the `type` attribute to tell the browser not to treat the button as a submit button.
EG:

```
<button type="button">Your button markup</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for that idea -- I'll give that a try later tonight and see what it does in this context.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you say

> to prevent elements added by UserScripts to prevent form submissions

i'm not sure if you want to allow or prevent submiting the form...

anyway, here is a `link` and a `div` disguised as a `button`: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/PvhUb/

[image: eee]

and if you post some of your code, i can help you with your script.

Comment: This is similar to what I was doing and it worked, except I could never match the physical appearance of native buttons.  Since this chat site allows users to customize their rooms, my ersatz buttons always looked horribly out-of-place.

Comment: thats ok. post or link your script so i can take a look at it.

Comment: The entire script is 5,000+ lines (159k), but I updated my question to show the code I used to create the buttons.